# difference between date with and without time portion

Tags: javascript, datetime

let's say that I have two variables: one that contains a date string (without time) and another one that contains the same date string but with time 00:00:00 like this:

```
var date1 = '2013-10-23';
var date2 = '2013-10-23 00:00:00';

var date1_time = new Date(date1).getTime();
var date2_time = new Date(date2).getTime()

console.debug('Date 1 time: ' + date1_time + "\n" + 'Date 2 time: ' + date2_time);
```

The result in the console is this:

```
Date 1 time: 1382486400000
Date 2 time: 1382500800000
```

Why aren't these two equal to the same thing? Shouldn't date1's time portion default to `00:00:00` since I did not put a time?

Thank you

Comment: Which browser?  I get NaN in FF.

Comment: It appears that the first version is 00:00:00 UTC, and then applies your local time zone offset. The second version explicitly sets it to 00:00:00 in your time zone, which is a different value.

Comment: If you want to drastically reduce these sort of issues with `Date`, try [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) instead.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested it on chrome and found out that

The first one gives you the timestamp for 00:00:00 UTC

The second gives you timestamp with your current timezone.

So if you substract them you will see +-your timezone:

```
var date1_time = new Date(date1).getTime();
var date2_time = new Date(date2).getTime();

console.log((date2_time-date1_time)/1000/60/60); //will print the timezone difference.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get exact what time the first variable is considering.

```
var timestamp = 1382486400000;
var date = new Date();
date = new date(timestamp + date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)
alert(date);
```

It all happens because of default UTC time zone and your current
timezone.

Comment: @j08691 So I think it should help?